# Enviar token con angular

Tags: java, angular, jwt

Tengo un api desarrollada en Spring Boot java la cual le tengo un token cuando el usuario se autentica, el token lo genero de esta manera usando `HS256` el token se ve de la siguiente manera:
EL TEMA ES NOSE DONDE PUEDE ESTAR EL ERROR O SI ESA ES LA MANERA CORRECTA DE ENVIAR EL TOKEN A LA API

Token:

```
Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJqdGkiOiJzb2Z0dGVrSldUIiwic3ViIjoiMjIiLCJhdXRob3JpdGllcyI6WyJJRF9VU0VSIl0sImlhdCI6MTYxMzA3NTMwNywiZXhwIjoxNjEzMDc1OTA3fQ.7hzHiA9V7z_3J53nHFzaQcS8TV5rem1-zP8P6YTC8N8
```

Metodo que crea el token en java

```
public static String getTokenUsuario(String ide) {
        
        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList("ID_USER");

        return PREFIX + Jwts.builder().setId("softtekJWT").setSubject(ide)
                .claim("authorities",
                        grantedAuthorities.stream().map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority).collect(Collectors.toList()))
                .setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 600000))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, SECRET.getBytes()).compact();

    }
```

// Clase que valida el usuario y envia el token con el cross

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200", maxAge = 3600)
//@CrossOrigin(origins = "*") Con este ya probé y tampoco sirve
@RequestMapping("/api/usuarios")
public class Apiusuario {

    CUsuarioVO vousuario = new CUsuarioVO();
    CUsuarioDAO daous = new CUsuarioDAO();

    private String token;

    // http://192.168.20.21:8080/api/usuarios/login?correo=jonnyal96@gmail.com&clave=123
    @GetMapping("/login")
    @ResponseBody
    private CUsuarioVO responseLogin(@RequestParam(required = true) String correo,
            @RequestParam(required = true) String clave) {
        vousuario = CUsuarioDAO.validarUsuario(correo, clave);
        if (vousuario.getUsid() != null) {
            token = JWTAuthorizationFilter.getTokenUsuario(vousuario.getUsid());
            vousuario.setUstoken(token);
        }

        return vousuario;
    }

}
```

En angular al autenticar el usuario recibo el token perfectamente sin errores y lo guardo en:

```
saveToken(token: String): void {
    localStorage.ACCESS_TOKEN = token;
    this.token = token;
  }
```

Y lo envio a una peticion para obtener la lista de usuarios de esta manera:

```
headers = new HttpHeaders();
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
    this.headers.append("Authorization", localStorage.ACCESS_TOKEN);
  }

  listarUsuarios() {
    console.log("tkn:" + localStorage.ACCESS_TOKEN);
    return this.http.get<CUsuarioVO[]>(this.url + "/listas/inactivos", { headers: this.headers });
  }
```

El error que recibo en consola es:

```
ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest': 'Authorization ' is not a valid HTTP header field name.
```

Comment: Verifica que tienes habilitado CORS en tu servicio Spring, así mismo permite la entrada del encabezado `Authorization`.

Comment: @OscarLudick no se cuales son los CORS aproposito tengo un error de esos, Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://192.168.20.21:8080/api/usuarios/listas/inactivos' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: Creeria que es esta anotación que tengo en el inicio de la clase:

CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200", maxAge = 3600)

Comment: CORS te permite solicitar recursos desde un dominio diferente, tu aplicación Spring y tu Angular no están en el mismo dominio. El CrossOrigin va a nivel de controlador, y debes especificar tu dominio como `http://localhost:4200` o utilizar un `*` para permitir cualquier acceso. [Lee este enlace](https://www.arquitecturajava.com/spring-rest-cors-y-su-configuracion/). Una vez resuelto eso, tu token debe funcionar.

Comment: @OscarLudick ya lo hice antes puse con el * y le dije tam bien que desde el localhost:4200 de angular pero aun asi sigue sin funcionar, ya edite mi código y sigue igual, la edición la dejare en la edición del código

Comment: Puedes compartir esa parte del código?, ya que si estuviera bien configurado, no deberías presentar esos errores en consola.

Comment: @OscarLudick ok lo dejare en el código en sección de java

Comment: @OscarLudick lo deje en la seccion de -> Clase que valida el usuario y envia el token con el cross en el cross tam bien especifique los metodos get,post,put,delete para que permita esos y tampoco sirvio

Comment: @OscarLudick acabe de hacer una prueba para consumir esa api en java con código que tengo y consumir el app y enviar token  al api desde java me funciona bien queria descartar si era el api pero ya me di cuenta que el error esta en angular (cliente) pero aun no logro con ese error en angular

Comment: Recuerda que todas tus clases con @RequestMapping también deben tener @CrossOrigin. En este caso la clase con `/listas/inactivos`  debe tenerlo.

Comment: Eso también lo hice en los métodos de una documentación de java que vi pero tampoco sirvió

Comment: ya intentaste esto `this.headers.append("Authorization", 'Bearer ' + localStorage.ACCESS_TOKEN);`?

Comment: @AlbertoRojas si asi lo hice pero tampoco la verdad este es el día en que logro que funcione